# NSTextfield AutoComplete like VisualStudio?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, nstextfield

How can I set something for NSTextfields in xcode for **autocompletion** ?

I want to have **suggestion** when I type in **textfields** just like what we did in visualstudio's autocomplete and how we define it's **autocomplete source**.

For example if I have a textfield that user will type it's name I want to have suggestion from previously typed names or an array resource to give them some suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into using [token fields](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thank you mipadi, I used tokenfield but all I want is to implement it to normal textfield as autocompletion like :  
`- (NSArray *)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index`  
But I can't define it correctly. Thank you anyway becuase tokenfield may solve my problem too.